# I can't figure out how to do undetermined coefficients for low level nonhomogenous diff. equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a very basic problem here that I am unable to solve, and it is not just this problem but many other that require the usage of this method. Consider the following differential equation

$y'' -3y' = e^{3x} - 18x$

I can solve $y_h$ easily and I get that the $y_h$ part is $C_1 + C_2 e^{3x}$

But now once I try to guess the result via the method of undetermined coefficients, I get stuck.

My guess is that $y_p = xe^{3x} + Ax + B$

Then I proceed to find the first and second derivatives which are respectively

$y_p' = (3x+1)e^{3x}+A$

$y_p'' = (9x+6)e^{3x}$

When plugged in, it gives me

$ (9x+6)e^{3x} - 3((3x+1)e^{3x}+A) $

which in turn gives something like

$ e^{3x}(9x + 6 - 9x-3) - 3A = e^{3x} -18x $

and finally

$3e^{3x} - 3A = e^{3x} - 18x$

What do I do now? Whatever I try to do I cannot seem to be able to get a system of equations to solve this problem.

Note: Symbolab gives the following answer for $y_p$

$$y_p = \frac{e^{3x}x}{3}+3x^2+2x$$

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to know that you multiply the $e^{3x}$ by $x$ because $e^{3x}$ is part of the homogeneous solution.

You have to do the same thing with $1 = e^{0x}$.  Part of the forcing function is $-18x$.  The derivatives of $x$ are $x$ and $1$, and $1$ is the other homogeneous solution.  So your form for that part of the particular solution gets multiplied by $x$:

$$Ax^2+Bx.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I knew I had to multiply $e^{3x}$ by $x$ because that is _already a part of $y_h$_. I did not know however that I also have to take in **derivatives** of $y_p$ into account, such as if a derivative of a part of my guessed solution is equal to a part of $y_h$, I have to multiply it by $x$. Am I correct now?

Comment: Yes.  That's why the method works only with forcing functions with only finitely many terms amongst all its derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Since $y_h=C_1$ is a solution to the homogeneous part, you need to use $y_p=\alpha x e^{3x}+Ax^2+Bx$ instead of $xe^{3x}+Ax+B$ for the particular solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a general rule that when $C$ is a solution to $y_h$ we have to make adjustments for $y_p$? because I did not know of this.

Comment: The "general" rule of thumb is: you need to multiply by $x^n$, least $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so that the proposed particular solution does not contain any part of homogeneous solution.  Just like you use $xe^{3x}$ instead of $e^{3x}$ which already appears in $y_h$.

Comment: I didn't know it also applies to _derivatives_ of $y_p$. The derivative of $x$ is $1$ and I already have $1$ in $y_h$.

Comment: We are applying it to $y_p$ directly.  The naive $+B$ in $y_p=\dots+B$ would be the same as the $+C$ in $y_h$, so you need to bump up the entire $Ax+B$ (we can't use $Ax+Bx$ because that reduces the number of coefficients by 1 effectively) by a factor of $x$, giving $Ax^2+Bx$.